# drupal 7 attach behaviors to ajax content

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, attachedbehaviors

So... I load a node form via ajax into another page. I try to attach behaviors like this:

```
Drupal.attachBehaviors($('.ajax-form-container'));
```

The problem is that nothing happens. The form has no behaviors attached (autocomplete, collapsible fieldsets, draggable textarea etc)

Comment: Can you please post your code? I struggle with this and nothing yet

Comment: what exaclty do you need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, found the problem. you have to manually include the javascript files responsible for these behaviors on your page before the form is loaded via ajax:

```
"misc/vertical-tabs.js";
"misc/states.js";
"misc/form.js";
"misc/textarea.js";
"misc/collapse.js";
```